# JQuery on click event listeners and functions, fire differently with different parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, addeventlistener

I have elements that when I click on them I need to run a function and that function needs to know what element was clicked on.

Example A:

```
var elements = $(".config-cell");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log("clicked");
            });
        }
```

When calling the function right there it works fine, however I don't know how to pass through the element to the function so it can use it.

So I tried using this method and found something strange.

Example B:

```
var elements = $(".config-cell");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].addEventListener("click", this.cellCrop());
        }
```

When simply calling the function located elsewhere I noticed when loading the window it just automatically fires the function and then it doesn't even add the event listener so any time you click after that nothing happens.

---

Bottom line I would like to be able to pass through the current element being clicked on and have it fire a function. But I would like to know out of curiosity why method B works the way it does.

Learned that it knows which to use because 'forEach' has a callback with parameters

```
.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])
```

> For instance: How does this call back know what is supposed to be
>   'eachName' and 'index'
>
> ```
> var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];
> friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
>   console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); // 1. Mike, 2. Stacy, 3. Andy, 4. Rick
> });
> ```
>
> And can you do this with .addEventListener instead of setting it as a
>   var?

That being said is there a way to have it pass variables with your own function? Like:

```
var passthrough = 5;
            $(".config-cell").on("click", function(passthrough) {
                var five = passthrough;
                console.log(five);
            });
```

Comment: `this.cellCrop()` calls the function,  `this.cellCrop` passes it

Comment: so if I wanted to pass 'elements[i]' into 'this.cellCrop' wouldn't I do 'this.cellCrop(elements[i])'? But that didn't work becuase it just fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `this.cellCrop()` calls the function,  `this.cellCrop` passes it. So if you wanted to set the listener it would have been

```
elements[i].addEventListener("click", this.cellCrop);
```

---

Now to actually get the element clicked on inside the function you can do it a couple ways.

Using [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) / [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) from the event object that is automatically passed to event listeners

```
elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
  //the actual element clicked on
  var target = event.target;
  //the element the event was set on, in this case whatever elements[i] was
  var currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
});
//same using jQuery
$(elements[i]).click(function(event){
  var target = event.target;
  var currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
});
```

Using the `this` keyword

```
elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
  //this will refer to whatever elements[i] was
  var target = this;
});
//same using jQuery
$(elements[i]).click(function(event){
  var target = $(this);
});
```

This would apply the same with using object method:

```
obj = {
  cellCrop:function(event){
     var target = event.target;
     /* etc */
  },
  someOtherMethod:function(){
     //...
     elements[i].addEventListener("click",this.cellCrop);
     //or jQuery
     $(elements[i]).click(this.cellCrop);
     //...
  }
};
obj.someOtherMethod();
```

---

> **How does this call back know what is supposed to be 'eachName' and 'index'**

Because documentation for the `forEach` method tells the person using it how it is going to be called. So you write the callback based on that documentation.

For instance the callback for `forEach` usually takes the form of

```
function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])
```

Which means inside `forEach()` it is going to call your callback in this fashion

```
function forEach(callback){
  //`this` inside forEach is the array
  for(let i=0; i<this.length; i++){
     callback(this[i], i, this);
  }
}
```

---

As for passing arbitrary data to the function, there are a few ways it can be done:

Wrap a call to a function in an anonymous function and explicitly call the function with more arguments

```
obj = {
  cellProp:function(event,a,b,c){
    var element = event.currentTarget;
  }
}
//normal anonymous function
elements[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
  obj.cellProp(e,1,2,3);
});
//fat arrow function
elements[i].addEventListener('click',e=>obj.cellProp(e,1,2,3))
```

In the above a, b and c will respectively contain the values 1,2 and 3

You can also use methods like [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) which will change the `thisArg`([see this question to see more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)) of the function but also pass in arguments to the function

```
obj = {
   //note event comes last as bind, call, and apply PREPEND arguments to the call
   cellProp:function(a,b,c,event){
      //`this` will change depending on the first
      //argument passed to bind
      var whatIsThis = this;
      var element = event.target;
   }
}
//passing obj as the first argument makes `this` refer to 
//obj within the function, all other arguments are PREPENDED
//so a,b, and c again will contain 1,2 and 3 respectively.
elements[i].addEventListener('click', obj.cellProp.bind(obj,1,2,3) );
```

[In the case of jQuery, you can also pass data in using an object at the time of setting up the event](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler):

```
obj = {
  cellProp:function(event){
    var data = event.data;
    console.log(data.five);
  }
}

jQuery(elements[i]).click({five:5},this.cellProp);
```

Comment: One more quick question. So if you wanted to pass through say a number like '5' and then in that function reference that value as a variable like 'five' so that 'five = 5' how would you pass that variable through and reference it? 

My guess would be doing like 'function(event, 5)' but then how do you associate it with that varaible 'five'?

Comment: Added more in depth in the question at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can make use of `$(this)`

```
$(".config-cell").on("click", function(){
   var clickedCell = $(this);// this refers to current clicked cell which can be used to get other details or write logic around it
});
```